# CATransition and Specific Execution Time

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, quartz-core, catransition

Look at this sample code (in AppDelegate):

```
- (void)showOtherView {
if (self.viewController.view == view1) {
    self.viewController.view = view2;
} else {
    self.viewController.view = view1;
}
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setType:kCATransitionMoveIn];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
[animation setDuration:0.5];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[[self.window layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"myKey"];
```

}

This method simply switches **view1** to **view2**. The thing I don't understand is, that **CATransition** is declared and added to **window.layer** after assigning **view2** to **self.viewController.view**. Why does the animation works?

I did set breakpoints and figured out that switching animates after showOtherView method is finished. Why? Just why **view2** doesn't instantly appear on the screen!? (at least for the first time I call this method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawing to the screen is an expensive operation, and [Cocoa only does it once per spin of the run loop](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/SubclassingNSView/SubclassingNSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH7-SW22), at the end. The effects of setting the controller's view -- it getting put on the screen -- don't actually happen until after this method has returned and control passes to the run loop. So whatever configurations you make to the new view will always be shown.